# Making bash autocompletion work

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, autocomplete

I have a newly-reimaged VPS server. Bash tab completion and history (via the arrow keys) works as expected on the root account but is totally absent on my lower-privileged account. I also can't navigate within a command I enter to fix typos by using the arrow keys - I just get something like `^[[D` at the terminal instead. My `.bashrc` is

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Is your `$SHELL` Bash or sh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going by your description, none of bash's command line edition features work. [I'm with muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338025/making-bash-autocompletion-work#comment596826_338025): the most likely explanation is that you are not, in fact, running bash, but some different shell such as dash. Keep in mind that `/bin/sh` is not bash — some distributions install bash as `/bin/sh`, but Ubuntu doesn't.

Check what your login shell is:

```
getent passwd $USER
```

If the line ends with `:/bin/bash`, your login shell is bash. If it ends with `:/bin/sh`, your login shell is dash, which is a shell intended for scripting, not for interactive use.

Run `chsh -s /bin/bash` to change your login shell to bash. Before logging out, make sure verify that you can still log in on another terminal.