# Autocompletion fails on <TAB> with `bash: !ref: unbound variable`

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, autocomplete

When I try to use autocompletion in a bash terminal with <kbd>TAB</kbd>, I receive the following error:

```bsh
bash: !ref: unbound variable
bash: words[i]: unbound variable
```

---

Additional details:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$ echo $BASH
/bin/bash

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Licesnse GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
...
```

Command's `getent passwd $USER`output is ending with `:/bin/bash/`

Comment: I wonder if you ended up with an older version of bash; what's `echo $BASH_VERSION`?

Comment: Add version of `bash` please. Issue `$ bash --version` in your terminal and edit your post to include the info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making bash autocompletion work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338025/making-bash-autocompletion-work)

Comment: Check OP in dupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338025/making-bash-autocompletion-work?rq=1 and also issue `$ shopt` in terminal to see what shell option you run. From there you will unravel the mystery...

Comment: Thank you for comments. I provided questions with some details

Answer (score 13):

The problem was fixed after command

```
$ set +u
```

Comment: Can someone explain what is this actually doing?

Comment: @CarlosGarcia Turns off the `u` flag. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Comment: I just encountered exactly this. I had sourced a script that contained `set -u`. This caused the `nounset` option to be activated in my main shell and triggered an exit when I later tried to autocomplete with the <tab> key. I assume there's something in one of the autocomplet scripts that references an undefined variable (but that's not my problem). The lesson I've learned is not to use `set -u` in scripts that are meant to be sourced and not to source scripts that are meant to be executed (and may contain `set -u`).